# Is this butter ok to eat?

Tags: food-safety

It was white when I bought it 2 weeks ago.

I didn't open it up yet. I was gonna open it up just now but I saw new yellow stuff and some green/grey stuff on it.

Should I open this up and eat it or return it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8GWb.jpg

Comment: I wouldn't, why risk it?

Comment: Ok, I'm mainly asking to learn how butters work

Comment: The grey/green discolouration looks like mould to me. I wouldn't risk eating it.

Answer (score 2):

`URT: 20/11/2021`
`SKT: 19/03/2022`

URT is an acronym of the Turkish "Üretim Tarihi", meaning "Production Date".

SKT is an acronym of the Turkish "Son Kullanma Tarihi", meaning "Expiration Date".

PN is an acronym of the Turkish "Parti Numarası", meaning "Batch Number".

Since it has mould before the Expiration Date, it has not met its requirement and should, therefore, be returned for refund, and the supplier can then return to the producer to report faults with the batch.